# Dont serve requests before site is warmed up on Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, sitecore

Is it possible to have some kind of timeout to make sure site is warmed app after website is scaled out or instance was restarted in Azure?

We are hosting Sitecore website on Azure Webapp and wouldn't like any requests to be handled by instance before its warmed up and instead served by other healthy nodes.

Comment: How are you hosting it? Web apps?

Comment: @Frans yes, its hosted on azure webapp with 2 nodes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use application Initialization to warmup the Azure web app. See [iis-80-application-initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization)

In the web.config this look like:

```
<web.webServer>
   <applicationInitialization>
      <add initializationPage="/" />
      <add initializationPage="/page-2" /> 
   </applicationInitialization>
</web.webServer>
```

Since it is for Sitecore see also this blog [warmup-your-application-on-azure-app-service-when-scaling-up-and-swapping-slots-using-application-initialization/](https://blog.baslijten.com/warmup-your-application-on-azure-app-service-when-scaling-up-and-swapping-slots-using-application-initialization/)